# Rounding many values in a csv to 3 decimals (printf ?)

Tags: csv, printf, paste

I have a paste command like this
`paste -d , file1.csv file2.csv file3.csv`

And file2.csv contains numbers like this

```
0.2
0.3339
0.111111
```

I want the values in file2.csv having 3 decimals like this:

```
0.200
0.334
0.111
```

For one value this is working:

`printf "%.3f" "0.3339"` -> `0.334`

But for multiple values in file2.csv this is not working:

`paste -d , file1.csv <(printf %s "%.3f" "$(< file2.csv)") file3.csv`

Maybe there is a good solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're close; you just need to tell `printf` to zero-pad to the right of the decimal point:

```
$ cat 736678.txt
0.2
0.3339
0.111111
$ for value in $( cat 736678.txt ); do printf "%.3f\n" "$value"; done
0.200
0.334
0.111
```

The format string `%.3f` means "a floating-point number with precisely three decimal places to the right of the point".

Comment: `printf "%.03f\n" $( cat 736678.txt )` also works.

Comment: I keep forgetting that `printf` will iterate to consume extra input.

Comment: That's wrong; both `%.03f` and `%.3f` mean exactly 3 fraction digits.  (For _nonfraction_ digits e.g. `%08.3f` and `%8.3f` do handle _leading_ zeros differently.) The differences that matter here are to have `\n` in the format string, which you added without any mention of it, and to _not_ put the `$(cat file2)` or `$(< file2)` in quotes, as per @Edgar's comment.

Comment: Thx.. but what can I do if "cat 736678.txt" is a variable?

Comment: If your numerical value is a variable, supply it to `printf`:  `printf "%.03f" "$value"`.

Answer (score 14):

There is a GNU utility called `numfmt`, part of the  GNU coreutils collection of tools, that looks as if it could be useful here.  It allows you to format numerical values, and the following command would format all values in `file2.csv` using the `printf` format string `%.3f` ("floating point value with three decimals of precision"). The formatted values would be printed on standard output:

```bash
$ numfmt --format=%.3f <file2.csv
0.200
0.334
0.112
```

As you can see, it uses "from-zero" rounding by default, but this can be changed with e.g. `--round=nearest`:

```bash
$ numfmt --format=%.3f --round=nearest <file2.csv
0.200
0.334
0.111
```

You may slot this into your `paste` command with a process substitution like so:

```bash
paste -d , file1.csv <( numfmt --format=%.3f --round=nearest <file2.csv ) file3.csv
```

---

If your file is a CSV file that is not "simple", i.e. it may contain quoted fields, then you may want to use a CSV-aware tool, such as [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (`mlr`) to process the data.  The following recreates the second `numfmt` example from above using the `fmtnum()` function in a `put` expression using Miller (this function takes a `printf` format string):

```bash
$ mlr --csv -N put '$1 = fmtnum($1, "%.3f")' file2.csv
0.200
0.334
0.111
```

The `--csv` and `-N` options make Miller read the input (and write the output) as header-less CSV.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `awk` to do all of reading, formatting and pasting:

```
LC_ALL=C awk '
  {
    getline f2 < "file2.csv"
    getline f3 < "file3.csv"
    printf "%s,%.3f,%s\n", $0, f2, f3
  }' file1.csv
```

You'll get as many lines on output as there are in `file1.csv` (with `0.000` for file2 or empty strings for file3 if those have fewer lines).

Beware that some implementations of `awk`,  including GNU `awk` when there's a `POSIXLY_CORRECT` variable in the environment honour the locale's decimal radix character for both input and output. For instance, in a French or German locale where the decimal radix character is `,` instead of `.`, `1.2e5` would be interpreted as `1` as the `.2e5` would  be not recognised and treated as garbage and you'd get `1,000` on output, breaking the CSV formatting.

Hence the `LC_ALL=C` above to fix the locale to `C` where the decimal radix character is `.`.