# printf "%.3f" ${variable with newlines} - error with \n

Tags: shell, zsh, variable, function, printf

Like [HERE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/736678/rounding-many-values-in-a-csv-to-3-decimals-printf) I have a **file.csv** with numbers in quotes:

```
"0.2"
"0.3339"
"0.111111"
```

To round the number (3 decimals) this solutions works great:

```
printf "%.03f\n" $(sed 's/\"//g' file.csv)
```

But now I want to store `sed 's/\"//g' file.csv` as a variable

```
var_sed=$(sed 's/\"//g' file.csv);
printf "%.03f\n" ${var_sed}
```

Doesn't work. The output is

```
zsh: bad math expression: operator expected at `0.3339\n0.1...'
0.000
```

So the problem is that `var_sed` passes `\n` to `printf "%.03f\n"`.

The only solution I know is:

```
var_sed=$(sed 's/\"//g' file.csv);
printf "%.03f\n" $(echo ${var_sed})
```

1. Maybe there is a cleaner way.
2. Also I want to put `printf "%.03f\n"` in a function like this:

```
printf_function () { printf "%.03f\n" $1;}
```

But this is not working:

```
printf_function () { printf "%.03f\n" $1;};
var_sed=$(sed 's/\"//g' file.csv);
printf_function ${var_sed}
```

also `printf_function $(echo ${var_sed})` is not working.

**____________________________________________________________**

***Why I try to save the file in a variable?***
**____________________________________________________________**

The truth is that I actually want to put the `sed` command in a function. I'm sorry I put this as a variable to (try to) simplify the problem.

My script is

```
sed_01 () { sed 's/\"$// ; s/^\"// ; s/something_else//g' $1;};
printf_03 () { printf "%.03f\n" $1;};
printf_03 "$(sed_01 file.csv)"
```

as mentioned in the comments below, it works in bash.

**output:**

```
"0.200"
"0.334"
"0.111"
```

but in zsh the **output:** is:

```
printf_03: bad math expression: operator expected at `0.3339\n0.1...'
0.000
```

Comment: I'm thinking the reason why `printf "%.03f\n" $(echo ${var_sed})` works and not `printf "%.03f\n" ${var_sed}` is because the command substitution `$(the comand)` removes all trailing new lines

Comment: Why would you want to save the file in a variable? Strip the quotes inside your function, pass an option and a filename as arguments. If the option is not present, quotes are not removed.

Comment: See also the second half of [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/736708/116858) to the question you link to, which is specifically about CSV input with quoted fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> printf "%.03f\n" $(sed 's/\"//g' file.csv)
>
> var_sed=$(sed 's/\"//g' file.csv);
> printf "%.03f\n" ${var_sed}
> ```

This relies on word splitting to give the numbers to `printf` as separate arguments. The thing is, that zsh has dropped automatic word splitting as a silly remnant of the past, and doesn't do it for variable expansions. But it does do it for command substitutions, for whatever reason.

There's also no splitting when assigning from the command substitution to a regular scalar variable, so the newlines in the output of `sed` get saved in the variable.

That's why your code works with the command substitution, but not with the intermediate variable.

If you do need to load the values in a variable first (and you don't for just printing), consider [storing them in an array (zsh)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/29724/170373):

```
lines=("${(f)$(sed 's/\"//g' file.csv)}")
printf "%.03f\n" $lines
```

in Bash, you'd use `readarray`/`mapfile`:

```
mapfile -t lines < <(sed 's/\"//g' file.csv)
printf "%.03f\n" "${lines[@]}"
```

Or if you want something that mostly works in either, you'll have to rely on word splitting again:

```
lines=( $(sed 's/\"//g' file.csv) )
printf "%.03f\n" "${lines[@]}"
```

Note the parentheses, they make that an array assignment, so word splitting again happens. <sub>("mostly" including the usual caveats of a modified `IFS` affecting the behaviour, and filename globbing also happening.)</sub>

---

Then again, something like this might be easier done with just AWK:

```
$ awk '{gsub(/"/, ""); printf "%.03f\n", $1}' file.csv
0.200
0.334
0.111
```

Comment: Most shells that don't have that misfeature of the Bourne shell of doing split+glob upon parameter expansion still do some form of splitting upon command substitution and not globbing  (rc, es, fish...). csh still does splitting upon quoted command substitutions (though line based in that case). Main reason is because that's generally what you want.

Comment: Note that in `zsh`, to split on newline, you use the `f` parameter expansion flag (short for `ps[\n]`). `non_empty_lines=( ${(f)"$(cmd)"} )`. Here in case some of the lines have things like `1 + 1`. Note that because `printf` in zsh (like in ksh) does arithmetic evaluation in numeric arguments, that would make this a command injection vulnerability if the input was not sanitised.